# Switch Site Name depending on URL

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I'm looking to switch my Site Name (admin/config/system/site-information) depending on what url I'm at.  So if I was at www.example.com/cat I could have the site name be Cats and if I was at www.example.com/dog I could have the site name be Dogs.

Doe anyone know of a module that has this functionality?

I know that this is similar to a multisite, but I just need to create a bunch of tiny blogs and a multisite seems like overkill.

Comment: I may just toss a block in the branding region that would have the site-logo and site-name.  The other option I'm looking at would be to check the path in the region--branding.tpl.php file, and then use a switch statement to set the site-name & links to the "home" of the Cat or Dog blog.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module.  Not sure if you can use it with subdirectories, but you can use it with subdomains.  Basically, you would create an "affiliate" (module's term for a site) for dogs and one for cats, and configure as needed.

Comment: I looked at Domain Access, but it seems like overkill also.  It is mostly for sharing nodes which I won't be doing.

Comment: It may be overkill now, but getting things like this set up in advance to plan for site growth can be a good idea.